# Using list to traverse list of lists

Tags: jinja2

I want to traverse list, and for each element of the list I have to traverse respective element of the other list of lists in jinja2.

The lists:

```
devices=["device1","device2","device3"]
device_ports=[["device1port1","device1port2"],["device2port1","device2port2"],["device3port1","device3port2"]]
```

Jinja Template:

```
{% for device,device_port in devices,device_ports %}
  {% for port in device_port %}
     {{device}} {{port}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected Template Output:

```
device1 device1port1
device1 device1port2
device2 device2port1
device2 device2port2
device3 device3port1
device4 device4port2
```

Error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Have you tried:

{% for device in devices %}
      {% for port in ,device_ports[loop.index0] %}
         {{device}} {{port}}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

?

Comment: Its working mate. I just want to know when we are using loop.index0 is it like its traversing the device_ports list one by one ?

Comment: (if I understood you right) Due to loop.index0 increases by 1 every iteration of the outer loop so yes, it's looks like you traversing two arrays item by item simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use indexing here. You can easily access current item index in the loop and perform traversing you're looking for:

```
{% for device in devices %}
  {% for port in device_ports[loop.index0] %}
     {{device}} {{port}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`loop.index0` here is an index of the current item in `devices` (i. e. `device`) and you can use this index to access corresponding item from the `device_ports`.

Comment: Thank you mate. Got it.